# .show() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having issues with an app I am creating.  Depending on whether a variable of mine is null is supposed to show a specific screen.  Once that variable has a value attached my app is supposed to display another div.    However, my code is not working.   Take a look at the Javascript/Jquery below:

(Note modifying the code in order to show that null is not the issue)

```
access_token = 3; 

   if (access_token == 3){
        $('.dashboardProfile').hide();
        $('.dashboardInfo').hide();
        $('.dashboardConnect').show();

    $('.connect').click(function () {
        var url = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
        url += "?client_id=" + foursquareApi.clientId;
        url += "&response_type=token";
        url += "&redirect_uri=" + foursquareApi.redirectUrl;

        window.location = url;
    });
}
else {
    $('.dashboardProfile').show();
    $('.dashboardInfo').show();
    $('.dashboardConnect').hide();
}
```

and this is the HTML in question:

```
<div class="dashboard-container">
    <div class="dashboardConnect">
        <div class="connect">
            <p>Sign In</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboardProfile">
        <p>User Information and Picture</p>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboardInfo">
        <p>Check Ins</p>
        <div class="indicator checkin">#</div>
        <p>Countries</p>
        <div class="indicator country">#</div>
        <p>Cities</p>
        <div class="indicator city">#</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--container-fluid-->
```

This is the head of the HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>FourSquare Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="FourSquareJax.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I tested this and it's working. http://devdoodle.net/dev/155/

Comment: @NobleMushtak interesting.  I am working this on Github and it doesn't work, and console doesn't say anything: http://almontas.github.io/FourSquareJax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix. You made a small typo. Put `$('.dashboardConnect').hide();` inside the `else` loop:

```
var access_token = 3;
if (access_token == 3) {       
    $('.dashboardProfile').hide();   
    $('.dashboardInfo').hide(); 
    $('.dashboardConnect').show();   
    $('.connect').click(function() {   
        var url = "https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token";
        url += "?client_id="+foursquareApi.clientId;
        url += "&response_type=token";
        url += "&redirect_uri="+foursquareApi.redirectUrl;
        window.location = url;
    });
}
else {
    $('.dashboardProfile').show();   
    $('.dashboardInfo').show();
    $('.dashboardConnect').hide();
}
```

Comment: I know it's exactly the same in the question _now_, but that's because someone else edited it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. I made http://devdoodle.net/dev/155/ so it mimiced the Github file and the reason it wasn't working in your Github file was because of this typo. @Almontas

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your conditional to:

```
if (!access_token)
```

This will cause the conditional block to be entered if `access_token` is null, undefined, an empty string or 0.